Why do published questions from the staging ground have a different ID?
I edited a staging-ground question (ID: 78787695) and published it, but the published version is a different post (ID: 78787910) with no revisions.
Is it the expected behavior? Shouldn’t revisions in the staging ground show up on the published question?

It's clearly how this currently works. Whether it should work in a different way is probably a separate question or a feature request. But doesn't sound like a bug.

No, revisions (and comments) on the staging ground are deliberately not transferred to give the question a blank slate when it is published. But the timeline does show that it was published from the SG.

@cafce25 it's also the revisions list - at the bottom it says "created from staging ground"

Even though this is the intended behaviour as designed, I acknowledge and agree there have been (and are) many issues (both potential and actual) with attributing all SG revisions to a different author (the asker).

@HenryEcker Not saying this doesn't have issues, but this is how migrations work as well. (They also create a new post that only links to the original article without also transferring revisions)

This is status-bydesign as you can see from Staging Ground Workflow: Question Details & Actions :

As such, neither revision history records nor comments from Staging Ground questions will be transferred to the newly published questions. The only indicator that posts originated in the Staging Ground will be a PostHistory entry relating the newly published post back to the original Staging Ground post, which will only be visible in the Timeline to Reviewers.

I'd guess the different question ID is just a consequence of both preserving the revision history on the Staging Ground post, but at the same time having a clean slate for the new question.
This behavior of creating a new question with only a link to the previous revisions isn't all that new, it also happens for example with a migration, the only difference is that this is within the same site. Though the Staging Ground is deliberately a different section and probably shouldn't be treated all that different from another network site in this regard.
